# Extend local history to save more data on changes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, revision-history

We are evaluating a project where eclipse should be extended in a way to enable more analysis on code changes. As these changes are already stored by eclipse in the local history, we don't want to save all data again in files on the system and are searching for a good way to efficiently build it on top.

More details:
Java files are changing multiple times in a lifecycle of a project. To build some statistics about developer habits, we want to store additional data as last time modified, username, some user input, and some more things. This data should be displayed in a compare view with annotations but should be a normal comparison view also.

We don't find any extension points or classes to extend, which could make this possible so we think asking here for help is maybe a try to find an answer/tip for our project.
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Local history is entirely internal to Eclipse and doesn't have any way to extend it. You could use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen to resource changes and store your information separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will look into this more deeply.